# Reshape/pivot pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pivot, reshape

I have a dataframe with variables: `id, 2001a, 2001b, 2002a, 2002b, 2003a, 2003b, etc.`

I am trying to figure out a way to pivot the data so the variables are: `id, year, a, b`

The 16.2 documentation refers to some reshaping and pivoting, but that seemed to speak more towards hierarchical columns.

Any suggestions?

I am thinking about creating a hierarchical dataframe, but am not sure how to map the `year` in the original variable names to a created hierarchical column

sample df:

```
id 2001a 2001b 2002a 2002b 2003a etc.
1  242   235   5735  23    1521
2  124   168   135   1361  1
3  436   754   1     24    5124
etc.
```

Comment: Could you give a sample of your `DataFrame` ?

Comment: @RomainX. for sure! edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to create hierarchical columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'2001a': [242,124,236], 
                   '2001b':[242,124,236],
                   '2002a': [242,124,236], 
                   '2002b': [242,124,236], 
                   '2003a': [242,124,236]})
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('(\d+)', expand=True)
df

  2001      2002      2003
     a    b    a    b    a
0  242  242  242  242  242
1  124  124  124  124  124
2  236  236  236  236  236
```

Comment: oh... well... that was exactly what i was looking for... thanks! now all i have to do is move the years to a column, but i think that should be easy to do w/ pivot/reshape